# Returning Postgres result in nodejs with parameterized query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, syntax-error, node-postgres

How can I return results with parameterized query in Nodejs?

Query runs fine if I remove `RETURNING*`

Right now, server returns this error

> error: syntax error at or near "RETURNING"

**server.js**

```
const text = "UPDATE users SET info = JSONB_SET(info, '{geometry,coordinates}', '"+coords+"') WHERE id=$1 RETURNING*";
const values = [id];

pool.query(text, values, (err, res) => {

if (err) {

//log errors
console.log(err.stack);

//return error to client

} else {

//success
//console.log(res.rows);


}
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a space between `*` and `RETURNING`?

Comment: @norie : no this doesn't affect the query

Comment: All the queries I've seen that use `RETURNING` have a space after  `RETURNING`  followed by either a `*` to return all fields or a list of fields to return. If there's no space after it will be seen as `RETURNING*`.

Comment: @norie : trust me I tried. Im scratching my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use postgres parameterized queries with node, the proper way is to use promise syntax. A similar issue was raised on Github [here](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/503) and [here](https://github.com/stanjdev/goodreads/issues/47).

It seems that the problem with the syntax I'm using in my question is that that pg is reading the $1 as part of the literal string instead of a placeholder because it is wrapped in quotes.

Promise syntax seems to be fixing this issue. Well, works for me.

**UPDATE Query**

```
const queryOpts = {
text: "UPDATE users SET info = jsonb_set(info, '{geometry,coordinates}', $1) WHERE id = $2",
values: [coords, userid]
}

pool.query(queryOpts).then(response => {
console.log(response.rows)
}).catch(error => {
console.log(error)
})
```

**SELECT Query**

```
var email = JSON.stringify(logins.email);

const queryOpts = {
text: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE info -> 'email'=$1",
values: [email]
}

pool.query(queryOpts).then(response => {
console.log(response.rows)
}).catch(error => {
console.log(error)
})
```